# Getting realtime alerts on answers to my questions

Tags: support, notifications

How can I get realtime alerts on answers to my questions? i.e. when someone answers my question I want an immediate notification so I won't have to wait for the daily email.

Comment: Have you considered the App? It sends me alerts more often than I want.